# translation ros to vietnamese

Tags: ros, translation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Currently, don't have vietnamese translation for ros,
I want create one page like http://wiki.ros.org/ja , where the guide I can follow?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258040/translation-ros-to-vietnamese/) by [science00000](https://answers.ros.org/users/25431/science00000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now I can create page.
http://wiki.ros.org/vn

---

Originally posted by [science00000](https://answers.ros.org/users/25431/science00000/) with karma: 20 on 2017-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on 2017-03-31**:
can you elaborate how diid you do that?

**Comment by [science00000](https://answers.ros.org/users/25431/science00000/) on 2017-03-31**:
the steps following :

1. sign-up a ros accout and request add user
2. when login http://wiki.ros.org/ click MoreAction (right panel)
3. select copy current page --> toolbox display then rename page ex: http://wiki.ros.org/vn
4. start edit copy page used text or guid mode.